# How do you store explicit 0 values in a scipy sparse lil_matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

scipy.sparse.lil_matrix objects do not seem to store explicitly-set 0 values. Other sparse matrices, such as the csr_matrix, do.

Consider the following example:

```
In [1]: from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = lil_matrix((5, 5), dtype=np.float32)

In [4]: x[3, 3] = 0

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
        with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

This is bad because sometimes there will be a 0 distance between elements of a graph (e.g., duplicates of a datapoint). If I pass a lil_matrix to, e.g., scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components, it will detect the incorrect number of connected components because the explicit 0 is converted back to "sparsity" and therefore treated as infinite distance.

I cannot use csr_matrix because it is very inefficient to assign elements to it. However, it will store explicitly-set 0 values unlike lil_matrix. Replace lil_matrix with csr_matrix in the above code and the output changes to:

```
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
        with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Does anyone know how to store explicit 0 values in lil_matrix objects?

Thanks.

Comment: The docs state that it keeps an internal "array (self.rows) of rows, each of which is a sorted list of column indices of non-zero elements."  So there probably isn't a way to.  If your data is floats you can probably set a very small (eg, 1e-20) distance and get a similar result.

Comment: Or you could instantiate as an `lil_matrix`, put zeros in as a value that is unused (max_int, nan, or -1), convert that to a `csr_matrix`, and replace all of those values.  As long as you only create the matrix once it should be somewhat efficient.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good fix. I think this could be a bug/unintended behavior so in the meantime I cross-posted this to their issues: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9417

Comment: It seems like converting to csr_matrix takes even longer than working with it to begin with, so I'll stick to the first method you suggested until the issue gets dealt with.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems fast if I index it efficiently.

Comment: `csr` doesn't routinely remove zeros because changing the sparsity is expensive.  But don't count on it preserving 0s.  There is a `remove zeros` method that may be called at any time.  And csr math won't distinguish between explicit and implicit zeros.  `lil` intentionally cleans up zeros because it is intended for quick value setting.

Comment: `pandas` sparse lets you specify other 'fill' values'.

Comment: Here is an approach for keeping explicit zeros with a Scipy sparse COO matrix, using the row and col attributes essentially https://stackoverflow.com/a/74931866/139271

Answer (score 1):

`lil` `__setitem__` uses a compiled `lil_fancy_set` function.  It's docs say:

```
In [320]: sparse._csparsetools.lil_fancy_set?
Docstring:
Set multiple items to a LIL matrix.

Checks for zero elements and deletes them.

Parameters
----------
M, N, rows, data
    LIL matrix data
i_idx, j_idx
    Indices of elements to insert to the new LIL matrix.
values
    Values of items to set.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

`csr` matrix has `eliminate_zeros` method:

```
Signature: M.eliminate_zeros()
Source:   
    def eliminate_zeros(self):
        """Remove zero entries from the matrix

        This is an *in place* operation
        """
        M, N = self._swap(self.shape)
        _sparsetools.csr_eliminate_zeros(M, N, self.indptr, self.indices,
                                         self.data)
        self.prune()  # nnz may have changed
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py
Type:      method
```

It also has `sum_duplicates` method.  This is used when converting `coo` format to `csr`, and facilitates creating a matrix from overlapping submatrices.