# How to Retain Expicit Zero Values in a Python Scipy Sparse COO (Coordinate Format) Matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I create a COO matrix, with zero values in the data array. When I query the new COO matrix data array, I can see those zero values in the array. However, I cannot get the indices for those zero values. I use the nonzero() method to retrieve the indices and indices for those zero values are missing. Does anyone know how to get the indices of those zero values? If not is this a bug in the COO code?

Below is example code to recreate the problem. The final assert is false, as the number of values is seven, but there are only six non-zero indices. I know that non-zero would clearly not include my zero value, but is there a way to use another similar method to get the explicit zero values?

```
sparse_simple = sp.coo_matrix(
    [
        [1.1, 0, 1.1],
        [0, 1.1, 4.1],
        [1.1, 4.1, 1.1]
    ]
)

sparse_simple_data = sparse_simple.data
sparse_simple_nz = sparse_simple.nonzero()
sparse_simple_data[1] = 0
(n_rows, n_cols) = sparse_simple.shape
sparse_simple_with_explicit_close_to_zero = sp.coo_matrix(
    (sparse_simple_data, (sparse_simple_nz[0], sparse_simple_nz[1])),
    shape=(n_rows, n_cols)
)
num_explicit_vals = len(sparse_simple_with_explicit_close_to_zero.data)
nz_idcs = sparse_simple_with_explicit_close_to_zero.nonzero()
num_nzs = len(nz_idcs[0])

assert num_explicit_vals == num_nzs
```

I have tried to find another way to extract the indices of the values, including non-zero values, in the documentation of Scipy sparse arrays but failed to find anything.

I have a fix for this, but it is a bit of a hack. I simply add a small number to all the nvalues in the data array and then this 'works'.

By adding this to the line above creating the COO matrix, this will identify the 'zero' value which is now a very small value. I fixed my code with this but I do not like it.

```
sparse_simple.data += 0.1e-09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: from scipy import sparse
```

Your sample matrix:

```
In [3]: sparse_simple = sparse.coo_matrix(
   ...:     [
   ...:         [1.1, 0, 1.1],
   ...:         [0, 1.1, 4.1],
   ...:         [1.1, 4.1, 1.1]
   ...:     ]
   ...: )

In [4]: sparse_simple
Out[4]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

You already fiddled with the `data` attribute; here are the others:

```
In [5]: sparse_simple.data, sparse_simple.row, sparse_simple.col
Out[5]: 
(array([1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 4.1, 1.1, 4.1, 1.1]),
 array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Adding your 'explicit' 0; not change to the "sparsity" of the matrix:

```
In [6]: sparse_simple.data[1] = 0; sparse_simple
Out[6]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [7]: sparse_simple.A
Out[7]: 
array([[1.1, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 1.1, 4.1],
       [1.1, 4.1, 1.1]])
```

But `nonzero`, true to its name, does not include this explicit 0:

```
In [8]: sparse_simple.nonzero()
Out[8]: 
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

It we look at the code, we see why:

```
In [9]: sparse_simple.nonzero??
Signature: sparse_simple.nonzero()
Source:   
    def nonzero(self):
        """nonzero indices

        Returns a tuple of arrays (row,col) containing the indices
        of the non-zero elements of the matrix.
        """

        # convert to COOrdinate format
        A = self.tocoo()
        nz_mask = A.data != 0
        return (A.row[nz_mask], A.col[nz_mask])
```

It starts with the "raw" coo attributes, but removes any "explicit" 0s - so we only get nonzeros, not nonzeros plus "explicit" 0s.

Sparse matrices also have a in-place method to "cleanup" explicit 0s:

```
In [24]: sparse_simple.eliminate_zeros??
Signature: sparse_simple.eliminate_zeros()
Source:   
    def eliminate_zeros(self):
        """Remove zero entries from the matrix

        This is an *in place* operation
        """
        mask = self.data != 0
        self.data = self.data[mask]
        self.row = self.row[mask]
        self.col = self.col[mask]
```

I've seen this used more with `csr` formats.  Changing the sparsity of this format is relatively expensive, so operations that create explicit 0s don't "cleanup" after themselves; we can do that afterwards.

Note that `coo` format cannot be indexed, e.g. `sparse_simple[0,1]` returns an error.  The `csr` format can.

So while it is possible to create matrices with explicit 0s, those are, in one way of other treated as exceptions.